# Как показывать слайды из папки? Slick slider.

Tags: php, slick.js

Задача выводить все изображения в slick из определённой папки. Как я понимаю это можно сделать с помощью php.
Подскажите как возможно сделать?

Comment: пробовал вот такой код:

$filenames = glob('/foo/bar/*.jpg');
foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
  echo "<div>$filename</div>";
}

Не сработал

Comment: `/foo/bar/` это абсолютный путь с от корня диска, очевидно, некорректный

Answer (score -1):

Рабочий код:

```
    $wimage = "";
    $fimg = "";
    $path = "images/"; // задаем путь до сканируемой папки с изображениями
    $images = scandir($path); // сканируем папку
    if ($images !== false) { // если нет ошибок при сканировании
    $images = preg_grep("/\.(?:png|gif|jpe?g)$/i", $images); // через регулярку создаем массив только изображений
    if (is_array($images)) { // если изображения найдены
    foreach($images as $image) { // делаем проход по массиву
    $fimg .= "<img src='".$path.htmlspecialchars(urlencode($image))."' alt='".$image."' />";
  }
    $wimage .= $fimg;
} else { // иначе, если нет изображений
    $wimage .= "<div style='text-align:center'>Не обнаружено изображений в директории!</div>\n";
    }
  } else { // иначе, если директория пуста или произошла ошибка
    $wimage .= "<div style='text-align:center'>Директория пуста или произошла ошибка при сканировании.</div>";
}
    echo $wimage; // выводим полученный результат
```

Comment: Зачем через регулярку создавать массив изображений?(( Почему бы просто не воспользоваться `glob`?

Comment: Я пробовал через glob. Выше код в комментарии. У меня не получилось. Прошу учесть, что с php у меня всё сложно.

Comment: Скорее всего не верно указан путь, указывайте полный путь от корня сайта. Используйте константу `__DIR__` например.